# Не определяется функция printf в eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

Не определяется функция printf в eclipse:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
  printf("Hello world");
}
```

Захожу в properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> includes , указываю путь /usr/include/c++/4.9 и заголовочный файл /usr/include/c++/4.9/cstdio, только тогда функция определяется. Как сделать чтоб автоматический определялась?

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что тут не хватает указания на пространство имен `std` - `std::printf`?

Comment: @Harry да нет вроде, все также не опознает. Первый раз перешел на eclipse из qt creator

Comment: Что значит "автоматический определялась"? Заголовок `<cstdio>` придется включать обязательно.

Comment: если JTAG раньше писал только на чистом си, но переходит на плюсы (а код на это как бы явно намекает и стоит тег с++), то неверное он не знал о том, что си компилятор (особенно gcc) позволяет не добавлять инклуды. Компилятор просто "выведет типы" (на самом деле попытается сделать  с них int) и сформирует правильный вызов. Дальше вступит в дело линковщик, который сам прекрасно знает, где такие функции искать. И если сигнатуры "сошлись", то все будет работать. Да, компилятор с линковщиком поругают, но соберут. С++ в этом плане сильно строже и этот фокус не пройдет.

Comment: @KoVadim, я видимо вопрос не доконца дописал. Дело в том что я подключаю заголовочные файлы в самом коде в начале, а в настройках компилятора мне ведь только нужно указать путь к ним(в моем случае /usr/include/c++/4.9 )?В самом коде заголовочные файлы определяются,я могу с помощью F3 перейти в них. Но функции объявленные в файлах не распазнаются, пока я эти файлы еще раз не укажу в настройках компилятора.  В qt creator и visual studio не нужно указывать в  настройках компилятора местонахождения файла cstdio.Просто пишеш #include <cstdio>,и он определяется.Почему eclipse так не делает я не знаю

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос информацию о Вашей системе, откуда и как Вы устанавливали eclipse и последовательность действий при создании проекта, которая приводит к упомянутым результатам. Пока из описания вопроса не понятно как повторить ситуацию, Вам трудно будет помочь. Поэтому приведите вопрос к виду [mcve].

Comment: пути к стандартным библиотекам обычно компилятор знает сам. И если ему не мешать, то он сам все найдет.